# My tkinter code will not run in python 3.8

Tags: python, tkinter, sublimetext

I am trying to learn tkinter, but when I try to run the code in Windows 10 command prompt, it quickly opens up another command prompt window and closes it again. The error message it gives me is on line one, where I am trying to import tkinter. I have checked, and tkinter is definitely installed. It does not let me run it through sublime text, or the windows command prompt. The code I have used is:

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
myLabel = Label(root, text="Hello World!")
myLabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I am using python 3.8. I would also like to add that the file seems to work if I select 'open with python', but only if I do so through the pycache folder. I'm not completely sure what this is, but I'm pretty sure it's not the proper way to do it.

Comment: Hello! What precise error are you encountering?

Comment: What version of Python is attempting to run the script? In Python 2.x, `tkinter` was `Tkinter`.

Comment: Can you capture the error code?How did you run the file on cmd and how did you check if tkinter is installed

Comment: How many version of python do you have installed on your PC?

Comment: @martineau I have checked this and I am sure I have it right. I only have python 3 installed on my computer.

Comment: @CoolCloud I ran the file on cmd by changing the cd to that of the file, and then typing `python file_name.py`, all on the same line. I checked of tkinter is installed by typing `python` in cmd and then typing `tkinter._test()`, which did work.

Comment: In that case it sounds like sublime isn't set up properly.

Comment: @Francos Try running the code in another IDE and see if it works. Also, on the topic of sublime, make sure your build settings are correct.

Comment: @Francos check on the IDLE too

Comment: @CoolCloud Yes everything seems to be fine here aswell

Comment: A common problem encountered by users of Sublime is that the default `Python.sublime-build` file executes `python`, which may or may not be the version that you expect. Classically it executes Python 2 when you mean to use Python 3, so a build that uses `python3` fixes the issue. However it looks like from comments above that the sample command you're using  is `python` as well. May be worth a double check that both of those are referring to the same Python version (like if the command prompt has a different `PATH`, etc).

Comment: Maybe it's some problem with sublime, python build. I remember it being cumbersome to use python with sublime(for me) so I switched to VSCODE and I liked it too

Comment: @CoolCloud I'm not sure that sublime is the problem, because I'm trying to run it through the command pallet. then again, you might be right. I shall try a different editor. I should say that I have just realised that the program work perfectly if i run it through the pycache folder. I'm not quite sure what this is but it seems that this is not the proper way to do this

Comment: yes maybe, im not sure either

Comment: @CoolCloud i have tried running it in vs code, and I am still getting the same error. all it says is `File "the location of the file", line 1, in <module> from tkinter import *`

Comment: it actually means tkinter isnt installed on ur python :( i guess ur vscode is running on a virtual environment